# How to load data into Power BI from S3 using an Athena query?

Tags: amazon-s3, powerbi, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I've managed to load data into Power BI from S3 via Glue data catalogue using an ODBC connection.

However, I would like the data to be transformed by an Athena query before loading it into Power BI.

Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Credentials for AWS Athena ODBC connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53971289/credentials-for-aws-athena-odbc-connection)

Comment: No, that question is concerned with getting a connection in the first place. My question is about transforming the data from a working connection using an Athena query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out I could just copy my Athena query and paste it in the SQL statement field under the advanced options when importing data using the ODBC connection:

[image]