# Simba Athena ODBC Driver with AWS SSO

Tags: powerbi, odbc, amazon-athena, powerbi-datasource, aws-sso

My company is currently set up to use AWS SSO for access to querying AWS Athena. I have Simba Athena ODBC Driver configured to use IAM credentials I get from the console, but it is annoying process to copy and paste them every time the session expires.

Neither the "IAM Profile" or "Instance Profile" authentication options are using the named profiles I set up in my ~/.aws/config.

Is there a workaround that anyone is aware of?

Comment: Maybe this guide can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56548727/12506028