# Simba Athena ODBC not responding

Tags: amazon-web-services, odbc, amazon-athena

Im working with AWS for the first time and need to do a POC on Excel OBDC with Athena.

Right now i have already followed this guide https://stackoverflow.com/a/56548727/12506028
The problem is once i test my Simba Athena ODBC Driver Setup it freezes.

[image]

Every box on the Setup is written except KMS Key and Description.
Have changed Authentication Options to default like the guide says and everything else is default.

I use a client VPN to access my AWS, maybe thats the problem.

I tried running everything as admin and still the same problem. Also tried using the IAM Credentials instead of Default like the guide. Same result.
Using Simba Athena ODBC Driver 1.01.19 and odbcad32.exe Version 10.0.19041.1

¿Anyone have a clue on this?

PD: English is not my first lenguage. Sorry.

Comment: By default Athena is exposed to public Internet, so no VPN is required. Please **disconnect VPN**, follow the SO post you mentioned to setup **AWS credentials** and **AWS CLI**. Then run `aws athena list-data-catalogs` and let us know the output or error messages you see.